# Make an installer which installs a toolbar post-install

Tags: c++, installation

My task is to make an installer for an application which provides an option to install a secondary app. The secondary app is one of those common internet toolbars. The main installer should also provide a few checkboxes which will modify the command line arguments for the second app.

I've done hours and hours of searching and tried one of them, but haven't achieved much success. I have tried the Visual Studio Custom Actions but I'm unable to understand it! I just want to know whats the simplest way to achieve this? (Please suggest some install creator solutions which are simple to use)

Comment: Please, don't. We have already enough installers that add useless Internet toolbars to the poor user's browser.

Comment: The toolbar is completely optional. Also I'm not doing this for myself.. even I hate those toolbars! :)

Comment: Both installers are MSI based? Can you use other setup authoring tools?

Comment: @BogdanMitrache : Second installer is an exe; first one - that is what I have to make. Could you please suggest some setup authoring tools?

Answer (score 3):

If you want a free and powerful tool I would recommend [Wix](http://wix.sourceforge.net/), however it might take some time to learn using it. It recently introduced a feature called [Burn](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/9/6/Burn-baby.-Burn) that does just what you need.

For a payed and easy to use tool I recommend [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/download.html). The Professional edition, cheapest one, has support for feature-based prerequisites, which is what you need. You can have the full package built in not more than 10 minutes. Just create a new Professional project, add your EXE as a feature-based prerequisite in Prerequisites page, your other application files in Files and Folders page and hit build. You will get an MSI package that installs your resources. However, if you want to have custom UI controls, like a new checkbox or a new MSI dialog you will need the Enterprise edition.

Answer (score -1):

The standard installer that you can script to do just about anything with also a huge community behind it is [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page). It's open-source, fast, extensible, light-weight, powerful, and absolutely free. I would say it's the industry standard for small to medium dev shops (InstallShield was the standard for the huge companies, but even that is changing now).

Comment: Last time I checked NSIS wasn't able to create MSI packages, which is what I understood tecfreak wants.

Comment: @Bogdan perhaps. His question doesn't say so, though I do see he mentioned that after the fact in the comments.

Comment: NSIS is indeed very good when you don't need an MSI setup package, just wanted to tell tecfreak before he starts putting more time in it. My choice for a free MSI setup packager is, as I said above, the well known Wix.